# Jquery plugin giving error in IE 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have a functionality in `JQUERY` which requires basic plugin of jquery to work.

While testing in different browser I came across that my plugin was giving error in `IE` as

> Object doesn't support this property or method

while the same plugin was working correctly in **CHROME**.

The plugin is

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

have a look at the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Jorrex/vt9nqddp/) which is working fine in CHROME but not in `IE`.

at line `return H||(H=n.Deferred()`

So I want a plugin which supports my functionality in `IE 8` and chrome both.

Comment: What plugin, what line?

Comment: @Justinas: the plugin `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` at line `{return H||(H=n.Deferred(),"complete"===l.readyState?`

Comment: I don't believe JQuery 2+ supports IE8, You will need to use the latest JQuery 1.x if you need to support the legecy browsers. https://jquery.com/browser-support/

Comment: @DBS: so which plugin supports, kindly help as I am not that strong in jquery

Comment: On the JQuery download page, it gives options for 1.x and 2.x, you need to use the latest 1.x http://jquery.com/download/

Comment: @DBS: it would be great if u give the link which supports `IE8`, and `chrome`

Comment: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery

Comment: jQuery is not plugin, it's library. jQuery 2 does not support old IE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JQuery 2.x versions [do not support IE8](http://jquery.com/browser-support/)

To use JQuery in legecy browsers you will need to download the 1.x version from the JQuery downloads page: http://jquery.com/download/

Or if you're using the [Google hosted libraries](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery) select the 1.x snippet.

The current latest version is:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: yeah, added that. now getting error as `Object doesn't support this property or method` at last  line of js code `return monthPart.substr(0, monthPart.indexOf("-")).trim();`

Comment: IE8 doesn't support `String.prototype.trim()` -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim#Polyfill

Comment: @Andreas: so what should I use in order to work in `IE8` ?

Comment: @coder The Polyfill section of that link has the exact code you need. We're here to help, but not do the entire thing for you.

Comment: "_Running the following code before any other code will create trim() if it's not natively available._" -> Add the code shown **before** the first usage of `.trim()`

Comment: @Andreas: thanks, added and it worked as charmed for me..!!! :) thanks to both DBS and Andreas..

Answer (score 0):

Use a fallback method for IE 8 as it does not support jquery 2+

```
<!--[if (!IE)|(gt IE 8)]><!-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--<![endif]-->

<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```